# Disable web.py HTTP TRACE

Tags: python, python-2.7, security, web.py, http-trace

One security testing on my web.py application says,

> HTTP Trace Support Detected

I know this allowing this will lead to cross-site tracing. But how can I disable this `HTTP TRACE` in my web.py app?

Answer (score 0):

web.py doesn't support TRACE natively. Best to check your security tester. You can verify using something like `curl -X TRACE` on your website:

```
$ curl -v -X TRACE http://example.com
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
...
```